# Block the secondary router in my network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I have a main router/modem and I want to share the Internet with some rented rooms in my house to cut down the Internet bill and make some profit from using the Internet. I am the owner and rent some rooms.

```
[Home Gateway]--[My Network]--[Switch]--- Renter Port 1
                                     |--- Renter Port 2 (And so on)
```

If one of them adds an additional router like this:

```
[Home Gateway]--[My Network]--[Switch]--- Renter Port 1
                                     |--- Renter Route/Access Point
```

My network becomes so slow and sometimes I can't connect to the internet at all. They share the connection paid for by one room with many. How could I block the Internet Access of this wireless router as well as these PC connecting to this router in my network). I have very little knowledge about networking but I hope you guys could give me some good ideas and I will try to figure it out.

Comment: Can you add a diagram, or explain a little clearer? How is PC3 sharing the internet to PC4/5/6 ? It sounds like you're using one internet connection for all of them anyway, if this is the case then it doesn't really matter what configuration you use unless you're throttling somewhere, or using QoS. Are you?

Comment: To this the way you want, you will need either a higher end router (SonicWall, Cisco Business series, Watchguard, etc), or get a higher end SOHO router with a guest wifi ssid that you can limit the bandwidth (higher end Asus for one). Then all renters use the guest WiFi and if you have a 20mbps Internet, limit guest ssid to 5 or 10. If you need wired connection, a higher end router is needed.

Comment: Please check the contract you have with your ISP; it is quite likely that you have residential internet, and there is a clause prohibiting the very sharing you're attempting to do.  Business internet with a contract that permits this is often not very much more, and usually has much better support as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your connection as a profit generator you need to invest in making it viable as such. Regular residential equipment will not suffice, and if you have a slower connection it may not be suitable for many users.

The way to do this would be:

- Port Security: a managed switch will allow you to register one device per port and nothing else can connect. This would make it quite difficult though not impossible for a renter to connect something other than the PC you register
- Use a captive portal with an integrated login server so that each renter has their own credentials they must enter

Regular guest wifi on a residential router wont work as it won't stop renters sharing the password with each other.

Comment: Strongly agree with your first para! You don't say _why_ captive portal would prevent password sharing though? Port security isn't a bad idea, it's supposed to help prevent bridge loops, and it should stop death by DHCP server / IP conflict due to plugging a router in. I feel actual security is an omission from your answer though; I wouldn't recommend having a landlords computer and tenants computers on the network without a firewall between them.

Comment: @sourcejedi I limited the scope a little so as not to overwhelm the OP. Really he should have a professional set this up, but in a small setup like this the finances may not be there for that. A captive portal should allow you to limit it to 1 ip per account so simultaneous use wouldn't work which in practice would probably prevent sharing.

Comment: Makes sense.  Don't do that, I want to use my phone in the house :).  OpenWrt (and others I've seen) will show DHCP hostnames; at least it's possible to check whether it's being completely abused.  You could implement the 1 IP hack by limiting the subnet size of the individual networks.  (/31 is a valid size for IPv4, I assume OpenWrt accepts it because Linux does.  Next size up would be /30 = 3 client devices).  I may have forgotten to mention this in my answer, but I have great fun with OpenWrt :).

Answer (score 1):

You would benefit from a professional.  Here is a possible design, which may explain why I say that.  Someone who's done this before would better know about cutting corners either from necessity or budget.

### Implement AQM on a router (which is upstream of *all* devices)

This prevents lag during use aka bufferbloat.  It's a widespread, ongoing problem, it can cause significant and even complete degradation as you describe.  Single-tenant networks get away without it: if I make my own network too laggy for what I'm doing then I can cancel the background download/upload that caused that, or find a way to rate-limit it.

It's very easy to check the lag your network experiences under load: http://www.dslreports.com/speedtest

A common target for increased delay under load is 100ms (0.1s).  The state of the art easily averages 50ms on slow DSL lines.  So 100ms isn't perfect, but it's widely tolerated for web browsing, and exercising any control over bufferbloat should put you ahead of the competition :).

Obviously the fact that it's an ongoing problem means you can't trust a checkbox that says AQM to actually work correctly (we've seen this in practice).  Or most likely the marketing doesn't describe it as AQM in the first place.

The cheap "brand name" to look out for is the open source `fq_codel`.  If a product is known for sure to implement this, then it probably knows what it's doing.  It's not exclusive; anyone building a cheap Linux router can enable it.  There's OpenWrt routers, which can be configured using a GUI, and Ubiquiti (US-only intermediate business provider).  If you can buy a router with OpenWrt pre-installed, the GUI isn't *too* bad, and there's a good AQM howto on the wiki.  Gargoyle has it's own weird AQM; they're open source and still in business so hopefully they didn't totally screw up the code.  I expect there's at least one other good provider if you know what you're looking for.

`codel` isn't quite as good, but may be slightly more widely available.  OpenBSD supports it and PFSense has a GUI that supports it.

So it's possible to buy a box on the order of 150 USD, with a GUI that supports setting up AQM.  The hardware will have a maximum speed it can run this at; I'm assuming you're under 50Mbps so that it's not an issue.  It can also support 11n wifi (the latest 11ac is not open-source friendly), which is useful (see next requirement).

Expensive & business-branded gear (i.e. Cisco business products and equivalent) claiming AQM is fine, but I believe Cisco gear requires an expert to configure.  This is a fairly specific skill; I think it would also limit who you could get to maintain/support the network over time.

Basically I don't have any personal experience with business-class gear that has a GUI for setting up AQM.  I know it will exist.  I can't describe how to distinguish it from cheap routers like the cheap Linux ones that botched their AQM implementation.

Rate-limiting might be part of the solution.  (De-bloating internet connections currently involves limited the rate to a set amount).  However I wouldn't trust that simply rate-limiting will solve your case.  Also you appear to have three renters or more.  If you divide your internet rate by four, the resulting rate is going to be much lower than necessary when I want to download a large file & no-one else is using the internet.  This is particularly noticeable for the upload rate, because in most cases it's already woefully low.

Once you've implemented AQM, *if* you use a service that requires a specific amount of bandwidth, it would be reasonable to look at  reserving that for yourself.  (I.e. limit the guest networks overall to total-reserve).  In practice this is about video or HD video.

Ideally you would allow guests to use that bandwidth when your network is idle.  That's perfectly possible, e.g. in Linux `htb` queuing discipline but that's a pro admin skill.  I wouldn't expect that feature to be available in GUIs.

Unfortunately I would say it's not possible to implement that reserve with just the OpenWrt GUI; it requires two boxes daisy-chained.  You can't set a single rate-limit that covers multiple networks.  But if all the guest networks are aggregated behind a second box then it could easily work.  I can highly recommend OpenWrt's fq_codel.  The hope would be that using `fq_codel` solves practically all load-related problems, and that complete outages are prevented by taking better control of the network (see below).

### See if you can provide one good wireless network,

At least to a large number of rooms.  Everyone wants wireless.  Everyone wants to use these permitted radio frequencies that are in short supply.  When you have many wireless networks in a small space, they can often interfere and degrade each other.

You are now responsible for isolating tenant's wireless, because they can't use a router of their own to provide isolation :(.

### Isolating networks

is a great idea, it just introduces another set of  constraints.  Note that another name for an ethernet network is a failure domain.  Isolating networks means that when Renter 1 inappropriately plugs the LAN port of a router (instead of the WAN port) into the LAN port on their wall... or plugs in a switch which has a cable going from 1 port to another... they don't bring down the network for everyone else in the house!

The future-proof assumption is that people have a wireless-capable printer, and a laptop-like device which *really* doesn't like wires either.  In this case you can't use the cafe-style "wireless isolation" feature (named after wired "port isolation") to help isolate every single device from each other :(.

Now each tenant would have to use a different wireless password.

The least constrained design is probably to get rid of the wired network ports altogether; people can always buy cheap USB wireless adapters for their computers.  (Technically it answers your question: there'd be no-where for them to plug in a router :)  The problem with wired ports is that isolating them requires a managed switch.  These are much more expensive than unmanaged switches.  OpenWRT can function as a managed wired switch *if* the hardware supports it (VLAN support); however OpenWRT devices will tend to have only 4 LAN ports.

OpenWRT has some instructions for isolating wireless networks - as a *single* network for guests.  ...That might be a corner you end up cutting in practice, it's honestly not good for your tenant's security, but it's very similar to the situation your current network is in.  Otherwise you'll have to experiment, or get someone in with a bit of experience with isolating networks.  The setup is in the GUI, it's not *too* ugly and I like the instructions, it's just that this is considered enterprise networking, not home networking.

You will have to survey the house to find whether more than one wireless access point is required.  Adding secondary access points is  doable though it does increase complexity.   The only constraint is  you'll have to think whether you want an integrated solution where APs are managed by a central controller.  Ubiqiti would be an example of this.

The complexity with multiple APs is to do with isolation.  I would recommend using layer 2 ethernet VLANs to multiplex multiple wireless networks over one wire, and then all the layer 3 IP firewall rules, DHCP server etc. can be on one central router.  I *think* you could use an unmanaged switch to expand the number of ports available for wireless access points (or, if you only need 4 ports, that the hardware e.g. for OpenWrt won't need to specifically support VLANs, only the software).

Randomly selected people will prefer wireless.  Clearly at least one of your tenants uses it.  There's a question as to whether your tenants have become used to wired networking... a classic example would be a "network hard drive".  Ultimately they may have to pay the price for being more unusual users.

Comment: Ubiquiti Unifi wifi access points are relatively inexpensive, and support up to 4 SSID's per radio (the better ones have one 2.4Ghz and one 5Ghz radio), each SSID can be on its own VLAN, and you can add AP's nearly seamlessly.  There are quite a few relatively inexpensive web controlled switches with VLAN capability; personally, I wanted 802.3af POE as well for a particular closet, and so use a Netgear  GS110TP - limited POE power, and working VLANs.  I would say provide wired ports next to cable TV ports in your renters rooms; getting some video streaming off the wifi will help immensely.

Comment: Thanks!  _If_ people manage to use 5Ghz, I think that roughly halves the interference diameter + provides at least 4 non-overlapping channels instead of 3.  (Wiki suggests indoor 35m range).  New 11ac devices will slightly increase the maximum data transfer per transmission op.  Marketing implies you could fit 40Mbps = 8x 5Mbps HD video streams in an interference domain...

Comment: But Dave Taht of recent bufferbloat fame claims Linux APs degrade quickly beyond one stream because they don't schedule packets into tx aggregates correctly (txops are limited to about 1000/s due back-compat interference).  So if you're sharing access points, I think that's a good point about trying to reduce the load from video.  Unless the limiting factor is e.g. a 5Mbps DSL line.

Comment: - for 802.11 5Ghz channels, it really depends on the bandwidth used.  See  Revolution Wifi 802.11ac Channel Planning http://www.revolutionwifi.net/revolutionwifi/2013/03/80211ac-channel-planning.html   - also, turn DOWN your transmit power as much as possible :).  Then adjust for your own regulatory domain, of course.

Comment: Yep, useful reference.  If you couldn't guess my assumptions - it was "screw channel bonding" :)  "In high-density areas, this should be 20 MHz... urban areas with many neighboring WLANs, etc."  And since I'm not procuring the clients (or not in the way a business would), I assume no DFS / "indoor" support, because I _don't_ want to fall back to 2.4Ghz.  My sole datapoint is from getting a WNDR3800 and being surprised that I only seemed to have about 4 (20Mhz) channels available on 5Ghz :(.